# understanding lotus, memoryless

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

I'd like to see what $E(X|X>a)$ means when $X = \text{Exp}(1)$

First interpretation would be

$$ \dfrac{1}{\int_a^{\infty} \text{pdf}(x)\mathrm{d}x} \int_a^{\infty} x\cdot\text{pdf}(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

Here we are using the probability of in our time frame, thinking anything can happen but just want to sum up the $x\cdot p(x)$ but only over $X>a$

Another interpretation would be

$$\int_a^{\infty} x\cdot \text{pdf}(x-a) \mathrm{d}x$$

Where you apply $\begin{cases}\Pr(X<t|X>a) =0&\text{if }t<a\\
\Pr(X-a<t)&\text{ if }t>a
\end{cases}$

Which can also be expressed by

$\mathbb{E}(X|x>a) = \mathbb{E}(X-a+a|x>a) = a + \mathbb{E}(X-a|x>a) = a + \mathbb{E}(X) = a+1 $

then this means, you are thinking of the events where $X>a$ only so there's no probability of $X<a$ happening.

I wonder if the first interpretation makes sense as well?

Yet another way would be
$ E(X) = \int_0^a xe^{-x} dx  + {\int_a^\infty xe^{-x}dx }$
So $ {\int_a^\infty xe^{-x}dx } = E(X) - { \int_0^a xe^{-x}dx } $ but I guess that's not what people mean

Comment: The first works as a general statement of the conditional expectation (and can also be described as *"thinking of the events where $X>a$ only so there's no probability of $X\le a$ happening"*) while the second uses the memoryless property of the exponential distribution.  In this case you get $a+1$ for both methods

Comment: @Henry oh thanks, I suppose they must come out equal then, somehow I failed to try if it checks out.. (I had an inclination they would not come out equal somehow..)

Comment: Can you explain what is "lotus" doing here?

Comment: @JeanMarie I know lotus by watching 2 youtube videos only (havard stat 101). Where you can apply pdf of X when you want to think of G(X) (instead of pdf of G(X)) . So here it seemed relavant when I thought of x*pdf(x) , then I normalized to make pdf sum to 1. looking back, I think somehow I failed to maintain the lotus principle. I feel there must be some expression of x*pdf(x) to express the E(X|X>a) . My x*pdf(x)/c used the modified pdf(x) .  thanks for asking.. I feel I need to find x*pdf(x) form to express the same quantity..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first works as a general statement of the conditional expectation (and can also be described as "*thinking of the events where $X>a$
only so there's no probability of $X≤a$
happening*") while the second uses the memoryless property of the exponential distribution. In this case you get $a+1$
for both methods.

For the first you get for $a \ge 0$: $$\frac{\int_a^\infty xe^{-x}\,dx }{\int_a^\infty e^{-x}\,dx} = \frac{(a+1)e^{-a} }{ e^{-a}} = a+1$$

Comment: Yeah, but then, I thought pdf(x) in the integral looks different, over x, and we are only normalizing the probability to be 1, I thought it may come out different. I thought it's closer to "thinking of events where X>a only so there's no probability of X<a happening but with pdf(x) from now assuming anything can happen (vs using pdf thinking X<a happend)" could be different.

Comment: I am trying to understand. Pr(a<X<2a) from current time is different from Pr(0<X<a) from time a, although X is refering to the same time frame. So difference seems to spring from where you are standing, not what you are looking..

Comment: Memorylessness would tell you $P(a<X\le a+b \mid X>a)=P(0<X\le b \mid X>0)$ (in you example, both are $1-e^{-a}$) and you can let $b=a$ if you want.  The left hand term might be interpreted as standing at $a$ and looking forward an extra $b$ and the right hand term as standing at $0$ and looking forward $b$

Comment: Yes, I see people defined memoryless as (<≤+∣>)=(0<≤∣>0) but then (<≤+) from time t0 !=(0<≤) from time t0+a , seems just counter intuitive and hard time accepting it. or hard time interpretating why I think it's counter intuitive. How can I understand the uneasy feeling.. where two seemingly same event (something happening between t0+a and t0+a+b) has different probability. I know it has to do with future self has shorter time span. so his world and probability assignment can be different,

Comment: but then, from past self perspective, when he thinks of future P(a<X<a+b|X>a) = P(0<X<b) from his perspective. He can think oh, event is memoryless and conclude P(a<X<a+b) = P(0<X<b), ie whether X happens under b, doesn't affect me when I start waiting for b because X is memoryless. but the reasoning must be wrong.. well I'm confusing myself..  
 math.stackexchange.com/questions/4685360/ …

Comment: That new question is at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4685360/understanding-memoryless-property